# Set the password to a text file using vim in a shell script

Tags: shell, vim

I have a text file generated by an application. Using a shell script in the application , I want to set password ( password is set by the application based on the account using which the user logs in) to the text file using 'vim' . I have tried using '-c'  and '-S' options but the shell script still prompts for password manually.

The main objective is to set a password to the text file programmatically and file can be viewed by authenticated users using vim.

Comment: Vim's `:help :X` is strictly interactive so there is no legit way to pass it a key. But why use Vim, an interactive tool by design, when you could use `$ man openssl-enc`?